# setting up my create-react-app and receive error for node installArchSpecificPackage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shell, npm, command

just cleaned out some files off my computer. idk what I'm missing

```
LambdaSr167sMBP:~ lambda_school_loaner_167$ yarn add create-react-app

yarn add v1.22.4 info No lockfile found. warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. 
To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json. 

[1/4]   Resolving packages... warning package.json@2.0.1: Use pkg.json instead. warning create-react-app > tar-pack > tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap. 
[2/4]   Fetching packages... 
[3/4]   Linking dependencies... 
[4/4]   Building fresh packages... error /Users/lambda_school_loaner_167/node_modules/node: Command failed. Exit code: 1 Command: node installArchSpecificPackage Arguments:  Directory: /Users/lambda_school_loaner_167/node_modules/node 
Output: npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND npm ERR! Cannot find module './lib/replace.js' npm ERR! Require stack: npm ERR! - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/index.js npm ERR! - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/extract-stream.js npm ERR! - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/extract.js npm ERR! - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/index.js npm ERR! - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js npm ERR!
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js npm ERR! - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js npm ERR! - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js npm ERR! - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     /Users/lambda_school_loaner_167/.npm/_logs/2021-09-22T00_33_35_034Z-debug.log internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-darwin-x64/package.json' Require stack:
- /Users/lambda_school_loaner_167/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:80:19)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/lambda_school_loaner_167/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:18:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
    '/Users/lambda_school_loaner_167/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js' ] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command `yarn add create-react-app` is not a valid one

follow the official documentation for creating your react app : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

example if you alreay have node & yarn installed you need to run
`yarn create react-app <yourappnamehere>` (note that there is no `-` between create and react-app)

You can also create your app using npx like : `npx create-react-app <yourappnamehere>`

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know how I missed that. A fresh set of eyes always help.